# How to find type and memory location of a defined symbol in Mathematica and Matlab?

Tags: function, matlab, types, wolfram-mathematica, memory-management

In Python, one can find the type and memory location of a function:

```
>>> def foobar(x):
...   x+1
... 
>>> foobar
<function foobar at 0xb764d224>
>>>
```

What's the analogue of this for Mathematica and Matlab, respectively?

Comment: Is this what you mean:
for example: a=10 ?? a (This is Mathematica by the way)

Comment: How to find out the memory location?

Comment: If there were a way to get this information in Mathematica, what would you do with it?

Comment: Why do you want/need this information?

Comment: Take a look at LibraryLink (the C interface of Mathematica).  It can give you some of this information.

Comment: @Szabolcs : could you please give a little more details?

Comment: @user001 As several people have said, perhaps you should explain what you actually want to do, and then you'd get more useful replies.  It seems that you are confused about how Mathematica works and want to do something misguided, but we can't clarify for you if you refuse to provide more details.  It would take some effort to write a full answer, and might very well turn out not to be "useful"

Comment: This is mainly for theoretic curiosity.  I am curious whether a Mathematica symbol `foobar` is implemented as a pointer at low level, and if its value can be accessed from a program in the language.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, you can run

```
format debug
```

in the MATLAB Command Window to force it to display the variable as its memory location, rather than as its value.  (This is an undocumented (AFAIK), but publicly known, option for the FORMAT function.)

See HELP FORMAT to determine what your current display format is, and more importantly, how to restore it, once you're done looking at the memory locations.